# Default value for pandas lookup when lookup value doesn't exist or is null

Tags: python, pandas, lookup

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
       parent region
estid               
1         NaN      A
2         NaN      B
3         1.0      A
4         1.0      B
5         2.0      C
6         2.0      C
7         8.0      A
```

What I want is to create an extra column containing the `region` of the `parent`, defaulting to `None` if the parent is not found in the data, e.g.:

```
       parent region parent_region
estid                             
1         NaN      A          None
2         NaN      B          None
3         1.0      A             A
4         1.0      B             A
5         2.0      C             B
6         2.0      C             B
7         8.0      A          None
```

The following returns the correct result:

```
df["parent_region"] = df.apply(lambda x : df.loc[x["parent"]]["region"] if not math.isnan(x["parent"]) and x["parent"] in df.index else None, axis = 1)
```

But I'm very scared of inefficiencies, given that my dataframe has 168 million rows. Is there a better way to do it? I looked at `lookup` and `get` but I can't quite figure out how to work with IDs that can be `NaN` or not present in the dataframe.

For instance, I thought this could work: `df.lookup(df["region"], df["parent"])`, but it doesn't like very much null keys. `df.get("region")` does not return the parent's region, but the column itself, so it doesn't do what I want.

Comment: How does `map` perform? - `df.parent.map(df.region)`

Comment: Extremely well :-) On a 100k row test, map takes 0.02 seconds, while my apply takes 16 seconds. On one hand thank you very much! On the other, it's annoying that the solution was so simple and I didn't think about it. Tunnel-vision, I guess... Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) method which functions similar to a dictionary. The values from *parent* column and *region* column serve as the keys and values constituting it. The mapping takes place if they share a common index between them.

Additionally, `na_action=ignore` could be used to speedup this mapping process, as all `NaNs` present in these columns would be ignored altogether and simply propagated.

Lastly, the missing values must be replaced with `None` using [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) method.

```
df["parent_region"] = df.parent.map(df.region, na_action='ignore').replace({np.NaN:None})
Out[121]:
estid
1    None
2    None
3       A
4       A
5       B
6       B
7    None
Name: parent_region, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also use a merge for this, joining on itself to match parents to estid:

```
z = pd.merge(x, x[['estid','region']],\
             left_on = 'parent',\
             right_on = 'estid',\
             how =  'left',\
             suffixes=('', '_parent')) #left join

del z['estid_parent'] #remove uneeded row

z['region_parent'] = z['region_parent'].replace({np.NaN:None}) #remove nans, same as other answer
z

    estid   parent  region  region_parent
0   1   NaN A   None
1   2   NaN B   None
2   3   1.0 A   A
3   4   1.0 B   A
4   5   2.0 C   B
5   6   2.0 C   B
6   7   8.0 A   None
```

Comment: Very cool and on my 100k example it runs practically instantaneous as `map` does. Upvoted.